# Fazer Consulta com uma data determinada - PHP

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados

Olá, Tenho uma consultas de pedidos, onde queria apenas mostrar os pedidos do dia atual e também os pedidos do dia seguinte, onde os pedidos do dia seguinte só apareceriam os que teriam que ser entregues as 8h da manha.

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida?

Comment: O que você já tentou? Coloque aqui o código que você já tem e descreva qual problema está acontecendo. Assim conseguimos ajudar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
//Query para os pedidos do dia
$pedidos_do_dia = 'select * from pedidos where data_pedido = CURDATE();';

//Query para os pedidos de amanha
// $amanha = date("Y")+"-"+date("d")+"-"+date("d")+" 08:00:00" 
# linha com o concatenador errado

$amanha = date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".(date("d")+1)." 08:00:00" 
//Linha com o concatenador correto

$pedidos_amanha = "select * from pedidos where data_pedido = $amanha;";
```

Agora basta executar os selects e mostrar os resultados onde quiser.

Comment: Tentei usar o código que me passou porém não deu certo. Esta pegando os pedidos do dia atual porém a questão de pegar os pedidos do dia seguintes agendados para as 08h da manhã não esta funcionando. Olha oque eu fiz:

Comment: $amanha = date("Y")+"-"+date("d")+"-"+date("d")+" 08:00:00";

$sql_sel_pedidos ="SELECT pedidos.*, clientes.nome AS clientenome, entregadores.id AS identregador FROM pedidos LEFT JOIN clientes ON clientes.id=pedidos.clientes_id_remetente  LEFT JOIN entregadores ON entregadores.id=pedidos.entregadores_id WHERE ((pedidos.status='0' AND pedidos.terceirizadas_id='".$sql_sel_terceirizadas_dados['id']."') AND (pedidos.data= CURDATE() OR pedidos.data='".$amanha."')) ";

Comment: ao dar echo na variavel $amanha, aparece o seguinte 2031, talvez esse seja o erro.

Comment: Desculpe, confusão de linguaguem, usei o + como concatenador, e isto é valido para javascript e não para php que usa '.', troque o concatenador.

Comment: Deu Certo, muito obrigado!!! segue o código para verificarem.

$amanha = date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".(date("d")+1)."" ;
$sql_sel_pedidos ="SELECT pedidos.*, clientes.nome AS clientenome, entregadores.id AS identregador FROM pedidos LEFT JOIN clientes ON clientes.id=pedidos.clientes_id_remetente LEFT JOIN entregadores ON entregadores.id=pedidos.entregadores_id WHERE pedidos.status='0' AND pedidos.terceirizadas_id='".$sql_sel_terceirizadas_dados['id']."' AND (pedidos.data=CURDATE() OR (pedidos.data='".$amanha."' AND pedidos.horario='08:00:00'))";